# How to remove commit and not merged branch

Tags: git

I'd like to remove a branch which contains only one commit.
This branch has not never merged.

This is the log:

```
* 3554555 - (6 days ago) SHA-1 to SHA-2
* 6526045 - (6 days ago) swagger updated
| * f9026f1 - (5 days ago) Using LocalDateTime (HEAD -> dates)
|/  
* bf2c6c2 - (6 days ago) Collect request parameters on audit
```

So, I'd like to remove this orphan `dates` branch and its commit `f9026f1`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is wrong with just deleting the branch?  The single commit `f9026f1` should eventually be garbage collected by Git anyway, or you could force a garbage collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+delete+branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can reset the head of the branch

```
git checkout dates
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

But frankly, since the branch is just a human friendly name given to a commit id, why not just delete it and fork a new one.

```
git checkout master
git branch -D dates
```